# What happens after I sign up for Sitecore Slack?

Tags: community

I filled in the following form to be included in the Sitecore Chat on Slack:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1bAVDgP5-FhFh8ohPchHtifq-rz7EBkuPojAzdEofJyo/viewform

What are the next steps after that? If I go to http://sitecorechat.slack.com, it asks me for an username and a password, which I haven't been provided with yet.

Comment: If you want to distribute the URL... http://bit.ly/SitecoreChatSignup

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your email inbox. You should get an invite.

At the moment, sending https://sitecorechat.slack.com invitation is a manual process.

One of the administrators has to approve your invitation based on what you submitted in the form.